# a javascript 'this' keyword tricky, when change data use vue2.0

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm learning vue2.0.
I want fetch data from remote when component mounted,
and refresh view when data come back.
the code is below

```
import VideoItem from './VideoItemComponent.vue'
import {fetchTop250} from '../service'
export default {
  components: {VideoItem},
  data(){
    return {
      items: [1]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('app mounted')
    console.log('before request items size ' + this.items.length)
    var se = this
    fetchTop250()
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(se.items.length)
        console.log(this.items.length)
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
}
```

in service ,I use Promise and axios to fetch data.

```
export function fetchTop250() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8880/v2/movie/in_theaters')
      .then(function (response) {
        resolve(response)
      }).catch(function (error) {
      reject(error)
    })
  })
}
```

after get data from remote , and run in **then** method ,
**this** keyword is undefined.
[image: img for debug]

I had searched [You-Dont-Know-JS(this & Object Prototypes)](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes),[Chapter 1: this Or That?](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md),[Chapter 2: this All Makes Sense Now!](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md)

I know if i define a varable reference this ,and use the varable in the *then* function,it works.
but i can't know the right thing.

1. I know **console.log(this.items)** function call stack is in **then** function context.so it can't call **items** in **mounted** scope，but why **this** is **undefined** ?
2. how to change items defined in data function correctly?

thx .

Comment: **this** is undefined because that is in a new function closure. In order to make **this** the same scope as the function it was called in, you need to add `.bind(this)` to the final closing brace `}`

Comment: You can use the new arrow notation which binds a function to its lexical scope. Here, your then callback could be rewritten as `fetchTop250().then(response => { // here 'this' still refers to mounted function })`